# Parent class generic type intersection error

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance, events, typescript-generics

I'm trying to extend the class **TypedEmitter** from the package [tiny-typed-emitter - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiny-typed-emitter) with my own class called **BaseClass**, then extend the **BaseClass** class with a class called **ChildClass**.

To implement some base events in **BaseClass**, I tried to pass the intersection of the events **BaseEvents** and **ChildEvents**(received as generic type) to **TypedEmitter**.

**ChildClass** works as expected, but when I try to emit a signal from **BaseClass** it shows the following error: `Argument of type '[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Parameters<ListenerSignature<ChildEvents & BaseEvents>["base"]>'.`

Is there a solution that could make **BaseClass** emit events too?

```
import { TypedEmitter, ListenerSignature } from "tiny-typed-emitter";

interface BaseEvents {
  "base": () => void;
}

class BaseClass<E> extends TypedEmitter<ListenerSignature<E & BaseEvents>> {
  constructor() {
    super();

    // Argument of type '[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Parameters<ListenerSignature<ChildEvents & BaseEvents>["base"]>'.
    // (method) TypedEmitter<ListenerSignature<E & BaseEvents>>.emit<"base">(event: "base", ...args: Parameters<ListenerSignature<E & BaseEvents>["base"]>): boolean
    this.emit("base");
  }
}

interface ChildEvents {
  "child": () => void;
}

class ChildClass extends BaseClass<ChildEvents> {
  constructor() {
    super();

    // Works fine
    this.emit("base");
    this.emit("child");
  }
}
```

Comment: Uh, have you looked at https://github.com/binier/tiny-typed-emitter#compatible-subclasses-with-different-events? It's `extends TypedEmitter<E & BaseEvents>`, not `extends TypedEmitter<ListenerSignature<E & BaseEvents>>`

Comment: @Bergi I tried that example but it gives the same error if I try to emit a signal from inside the BaseClass: `class Animal<E extends ListenerSignature<E> = ListenerSignature<unknown>> extends TypedEmitter<
  { spawn: () => void } & E
> {
  constructor() {
    super();

    // Argument of type '[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Parameters<({ spawn: () => void; } & E)["spawn"]>'.
    this.emit("spawn");
  }
}`